# Find the empty part

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

[image]

I tried several hours to figure out and tried all possible way i could think but didn't worked well.
hope this question does not seem silly.

Comment: All your questions seem to be from the High IQ Society founded by Xavier Jouve.

Comment: user53678, this looks like a puzzle you found somewhere else. Please provide a source for it, and make sure you have permission to post it here.

Comment: This is from an JCTI test that now already closed, and even someone unknown copied(backed up) that test and uploaded to google playstore with named 'IQ Test Spatial' and i took this from that App. if this cause serious problem, i'll delete this post.

Comment: @user53678 it's most likely not a problem, but please add the source to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is:

> 2

because:

> For the two on the left, the bottom reaches a state equal to the one above it if you:
>  1. 'Slide' the "12'o clock" hand/stick down a distance equal to its length
>  2. 'Slide' the "7:30" hand/stick to the top right (same orientation and direction as it currently exists) a distance equal to it's length.
>  Now for the shape on the bottom right:
>  1. Perform the same 'slide' operations, but assume that the edges of the shape wrap, seemingly cutting the moving lines in half.
>  I feel like this is really hard to portray, so if it's not clear I'll try to elaborate.
>  Edit: Here's an image having slid the pieces but not yet wrapped them around the edge. Please excuse my poor art skills haha
>  [image: After you 'slide' but before the wrapping around the edges]

Comment: Great observation, which seems to apply to *nyy yvarf*.

Comment: That's true. The rot13(qverpgvba) is somewhat arbitrary as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. i was trying hard to interpret english which i'm really poor at.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped!

Answer (score -1):

The answer is

> 1

because

> The image is "flipped" upwards (turned upside down), then reflected vertically. Alternatively: rotated 180 degrees to either the left or right.

Comment: So where did the rotation come from?

Comment: Re edit: is only rotated 90 deg.

Comment: @WeatherVane I mean from the starting position...

Comment: I think your answer is right but your wording is undoing itself. rot13(lbh syvccrq iregvpnyyl gura ersyrpgrq bire gur k-nkvf NXN gur fnzr guvat.)

Comment: @Veskah so what's the difference between flip and reflect?

Comment: @WeatherVane As far as i'm concerned, nothing unless you're using a coordinate grid

Comment: The example image is rotated 180 deg, number 1 is rotated 90 deg.

Comment: @WeatherVane oh, this is probably incorrect then. I was eyeballing it, lol